# how to process modis NDVI data range to normal -1 to 1

Tags: qgis

I downloaded MODIS Vegetation Indices 16-day L3 Global 500m (MOD13A1) from which i only loaded NDVI value. but the range is 5.25478e+06 to 7.76892e+07. how should I convert it into normal NDVI range of -1 to 1